# Can not pass date to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a table td as follows .

```
$roomRowId.append("<td  onclick='updateBookingRooms(" + roomId + "," + date + ")'></td>");
```

When user click this td i have to call javascript function

**updateBookingRooms(id,date)**.

id becomes true value but date is not true vaue.

**For example ,
if updateBookingRooms(1,02/04/2013) i receive id=1 and date = 0.00012419274714356681**

What is the problem?How can i retrieve original date value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parenthesis for the arguments:

```
$roomRowId.append("<td  onclick='updateBookingRooms(\"" + roomId + "\", \"" + date + "\")'></td>");
```

You can also attach the click event like this:

```
$('<td></td>').appendTo($roomRowId).click([roomId, date], updateBookingRooms);
```

Comment: Thanks..Its awesome...You save my day.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to avoid using string concatenations when manipulating the DOM. Instead jQuery has a nice way to build a DOM element:

```
$roomRowId.append(
    $('<td/>', {
        text: 'some text that goes inside the td',
        click: function() {
            updateBookingRooms(roomId, date);
        }
    })
);
```

It's not very clear from your example whether `roomId` and `date` are javascript variables that you want to pass to the function or whether those are hardcoded values.

Comment: I think that deserves +1 just for working out what on earth the OP wanted. It was certainly unclear to me. So why was the string being treated as an arithmetic expression? Or was that pure coincidence?